# How to optimize Macro Code That Looks into 2 Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Problem:

I have 1 Excel Sheet with 2 tabs
Tab 1 = Shipment Package
Tab 2 = Mass Update Steps

1. I want to go through all the values in column B of Tab 2 one by one.
2. As I go through each row in Tab 2, I will select and copy the values in column C and D of Tab 2.
3. After selecting and copying, I want to find Tab 2-column B's corresponding values in Tab 1 column G.
4. If a match is found, I will select  column E of Tab 1 (in row where the match was found),  and paste there the values copied from Tab 2.

So far this is the code I have which works. However the values from being searched are hard coded. With the values growing in number in Tab 2, the code is hard to maintain. I would like to optimize it. I have googled several possible solutions. But I keep on getting these run-time errors when declaring or setting the range for the 2 sheets. Here is my code.

```
Private Sub btn_Updt_Steps_Click()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Sheets("Shipment Package")
    .Activate
        lastRow = .Range("G65000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If (InStr(1, .Range("G" & i).Value, "Code 001", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            Sheets("Mass Update Steps").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("C4:D4").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Shipment Package").Activate
            .Range("E" & i).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        ElseIf (InStr(1, .Range("G" & i).Value, "Code 002", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            Sheets("Mass Update Steps").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("C5:D5").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Shipment Package").Activate
            .Range("E" & i).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        ElseIf (InStr(1, .Range("G" & i).Value, "Code 003", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            Sheets("Mass Update Steps").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("C6:D6").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Shipment Package").Activate
            .Range("E" & i).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        End If

    Next

End With

NotFoundErr:
    Debug.Print "value not found"
End Sub
```

Solution:

Private Sub btn_Updt_Steps_Click()

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Tab2ColC As String
Dim Tab2ColD As String
Dim Tab1ColE As String
Dim Tab1ColF As String

Tab1 = "Shipment Package"
Tab2 = "Mass Update Steps"

With Worksheets(Tab1)
     LastRowTab1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row 'LastRowInColumn(2, Tab1)
End With

With Worksheets(Tab2)
     LastRowTab2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'LastRowInColumn(2, Tab2)
End With


For i = 4 To LastRowTab2

    Tab2ColumnB = Trim(Sheets(Tab2).Range("B" & i).Value)
    Sheets(Tab2).Activate
    If Tab2ColumnB <> "" Then
        Tab2ColC = "C" & i
        Tab2ColD = "D" & i
        ActiveSheet.Range(Tab2ColC, Tab2ColD).Copy

        For j = 16 To LastRowTab1
            Tab1ColumnG = Trim(Sheets(Tab1).Range("G" & j).Value)

            If Tab1ColumnG = Tab2ColumnB Then
                Sheets(Tab1).Activate
                Tab1ColE = "E" & j
                Tab1ColF = "F" & j
                Sheets(Tab1).Range(Tab1ColE, Tab1ColF).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            End If

        Next
    End If

Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Your second step is not clear. Columns C and D are copied from tab 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For optimization, you can avoid select statements, activate statements etc. Check the code below.

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If YourCondn1 Then
        Sheets("Mass Update Steps").Range("C4:D4").Copy
        Sheets("Shipment Package").Range("E" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf YourCondn2 Then
        Sheets("Mass Update Steps").Range("C5:D5").Copy
        Sheets("Shipment Package").Range("E" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ElseIf YourCondn3 Then
        Sheets("Mass Update Steps").Range("C6:D6").Copy
        Sheets("Shipment Package").Range("E" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Next
```

Adding the code that you require. Hope this will work. I haven't tested it. Please check.

```
Private Sub btn_Updt_Steps_Click()
    'Finding LastRow in Tab 2
    Tab1 = "Shipment Package"
    Tab2 = "Mass Update Steps"
    With Worksheets(Tab2)
        LastRowTab2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'LastRowInColumn(2, Tab2)
    End With
    MatchFound = 0
    For i = 1 To LastRowTab2
        'checking whether value in tab2 column b is same as tab1 column g
        Tab2ColumnB = Trim(Sheets(Tab2).Range("B" & i).Value)
        Tab1ColumnG = Trim(Sheets(Tab1).Range("G" & i).Value)
        If Tab2ColumnB = Tab1ColumnG Then
            Tab2ColumnC = Trim(Sheets(Tab2).Range("C" & i).Value)
            Tab2ColumnD = Trim(Sheets(Tab2).Range("D" & i).Value)
            Sheets(Tab1).Range("E" & i).Value = Tab2ColumnC
            Sheets(Tab1).Range("F" & i).Value = Tab2ColumnD
            MatchFound = MatchFound + 1
        End If
    Next
    If MatchFound = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matches found"
    ElseIf MatchFound > 0 Then
        MsgBox MatchFound & " matches were found."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. However, what I am trying to avoid is hardcoding the value to be searched (this would be the "Code 001", "Code 002" in the code I pasted). If I go with the code above, I would basically be repeating the code I already have.

Comment: The code above was just for optimization. Will try to help you out with the code logic.

Comment: Thanks Ian! This is much appreciated.

Comment: I have added the code that may work for you. Please check and inform. :)

Comment: Hello Ian. The columns to be compared are Tab2-columnB and Tab1-columnG. I have tried to use the code below for optimization but I got a run time error:

Comment: You can just change it in the code. Anyway I will edit. Give the error details.

Comment: Private Sub btn_Updt_Steps_Click() Dim lastRow1 As Range Dim lastRow2 As Range Dim i As Long Dim j As Long Dim varCode As Long Set lastRow1 = Sheets("Mass Update Steps").Range("B4", Range("B65000").End(xlUp)) Set lastRow2 = Sheets("Shipment Package").Range("G16", Range("G65000").End(xlUp))

Comment: For i = 1 To lastRow1 If ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then 'varCode = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value ActiveSheet.Range("C:D" & i).Select Selection.Copy For j = 1 To lastRow2 If (InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("G" & j).Value, varCode, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then ActiveSheet.Range("E" & j).Select ActiveSheet.Paste End If Next j End If Next i

Comment: You need not use the optimization code. You can just use the second code as such. It will work.

Comment: Hello Ian. I tried the updated code and got a Run time error 9. I have added the ff. lines

Comment: Dim LastRowTab2 As Integer
 Dim Tab1ColumnG As String
 Dim Tab2ColumnB As String
 Dim Tab2ColumnC As String
 Dim Tab2ColumnD As String

Comment: I can send a copy of the excel file if that helps.

Comment: Pls share the excel file. Upload somewhere and give the link.

Comment: Will do Ian. I need to go home first. Storage sites are banned from my office.

Comment: Hello Ian. Here is a link to the file. It's Example.xlsx http://wikisend.com/download/394450/Example.xlsx

Comment: Hi Eli, the issue was that your tab2 name was "Mass Update Steps" and in the code the name of the sheet was "Mass Update". I have edited the code accordingly and it is working. Please mark this as answer.

Comment: Hello Ian. The code you gave didn't exactly resolve the issue at hand but come very very very close. With that I was able to create the solution I was looking for. I have updated the original issue to include the solution. Thank you for all the help. You made it so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want with simple Excel formulas.

In `Shipment Package`, type the following into `E1` and `F1` and then drag formula down:

```
E1 = VLOOKUP(G1,'Mass Update Steps'!$B$1:$D$20,2,0)
F1 = VLOOKUP(G1,'Mass Update Steps'!$B$1:$D$20,3,0)
```

*NB - you'll need to amend $B$1:$D$20 depending on how much data you have in Mass Update*

Finally, this assumes that there is always a match. If not, and you want to get rid of those pesky `#N/A` values, then update the formuals with `ISNA` e.g.

```
E1 = IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(G1,'Mass Update Steps'!$B$1:$D$4,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP(G1,'Mass Update Steps'!$B$1:$D$4,2,0))
```

Hope that helps.